# Viewing js enabled page in UWP Webview

Tags: uwp

Hi I am trying to open a webpage and display it's contents within a UWP Webview.

I am presuming that I doing something wrong as the topic is quite new to me.

My main routine:

```
WebViewSettings webSettings = WebviewControll.Settings;
webSettings.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;
WebviewControll.Navigate(new Uri("https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html", UriKind.Absolute));
```

saw some comments about enabling with my Package.appxmanifest:

```
  <uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
    <uap:Rule Match="ms-appx-web:///Web/App.html" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" Type="include"/>
  </uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
</Application>
```

my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <WebView x:Name="WebviewControll" Height="auto" Width="auto"  >
    </WebView>

</Grid>
```

expected Result:

[image]

actual:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the new [WebView2 control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/). Use the `WebView2` control instead of the old `WebView` control. Using the `WebView2` control, I could see the html page is shown correctly.

To use the `WebView2` in your UWP app, you will need to install the **Microsoft.Web.WebView2** and **Microsoft.UI.Xaml-2.8** NuGet package.

Use it like the old WebView:

```
<control:WebView2 x:Name="wv2" Source="https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html"/>
```

For more information, please check this document:[Get started with WebView2 in WinUI 2 (UWP) apps (public preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui2)